# loop with 2 counters

Tags: java

I took a string, turned it into an array, and now i need to call specific ranges of the array Ex:  symbolsArray [1-5] and increment the range by 5.( [6-10] )

```
public static String getNumber(String symbols){

    String symbolsArray [] = symbols.split("");
    int a =2;
    int b = 6;
    for (int i=5; i < 31;i+=5){

        if (symbolsArray[a-b]== ... ){
            System.out.println(...);
        } else() {
            System.out.println(...);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I show the values of the array from position a to position b? That is my question.

Comment: You might wish to be a little less creative in your indentation style in order to make your code easier for us to read.

Comment: `a = 2`, `b = 6`... `a - b = -4`... hmm...

Comment: @Mystical but how? I am not subtracting a and b?

Comment: No, you're still flush left on several lines. I've edited your post further.

Comment: You're not subtracting a and b?? `symbolsArray[a-b]`!

Comment: @ Hivercraft Full of Eels thanks

Comment: Isn't that how i get the array to get the range from value of a to value of b?

Comment: Please do the math. Your question isn't a Java question but a basic algebra question.

Comment: Actually it's a "check the syntax description" one ... @Tooilia: if you want a new array from 2 to 6 , you'll have to use `substring`method of the String class before turning it into the array.

Comment: How do I show the values of the array from position a to position b? That is my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

```
int a =2;
int b = 6;
//...
symbolsArray[a-b]
```

Arrays are indexed starting from `0`, `a-b` is clearly `-4` in your example code...

Besides:

1. Comparing strings using `==` most likely won't work: `symbolsArray[a-b]== ...`
2. Are you absolutely sure `symbolsArray` will always have 35 elements?
3. What is `symbols.split("")` doing? What kind of separator is that?

Comment: How to I get the values from a to b? I am not trying to subtract them.

Comment: 2.) yes 3.) That is how I coverted the string into a string array.

Comment: @Tooilia: I believe what you really need is: `symbols.substring(i, i + 5).equals("A...E")` here

Comment: @Tooilia use symbols.toCharArray() instead

Answer (score 0):

[a-b] = -4, which is **really out of bound**

For values from `a to b ie 2 to 6`, try this...

```
for(int i=2 ; i<5 ; i++){

System.out.println(symbolsArray[i]);

}
```

`Array's SIZE` Once initialized **Cannot be changed**

**-** If you want something `dynamic`, better go with `Collection`... `ArrayList` will be ok in your case...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right in what you're trying to do I would take a different approach:

```
public static String getNumber(String symbols){

    for (int i=0; i < 31; i+=5) {
        if (symbols.substring(i, i+4).equals(...)){
            System.out.println(...);
        } else() {
            System.out.println(...);
        }
    }
}
```

This iterates over the string as substrings of length 5 and compares them to something.